# Very basic question about vectorial representation of an electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, wave

This might sound a dumb question but I have some confusion about relating em fields as propagating vectors.

Below shows how an electromagnetic wave travels:

[image]

But let's focus and look at point X below:

[image]

The point X is outside of the E and H vector fields.

Does that mean there is no electric or magnetic field at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x and z directions in this graph are not spatial dimensions. 'x' is magnetic field and 'z' is electric field. 'y' is the only spatial dimension in the graph. So your point 'X' just represents a condition of a certain electric field for a different (stronger) EM wave (or DC field).

The graph is likely meant to represent the fields of a plane wave, because that's a relatively easy situation to analyze. In a plane wave travelling along the 'y' direction, the fields don't depend on location in the 'x' or 'z' directions. So if you meant your mark 'X' to represent a point in space offset from some reference 'x' and 'z', then the fields at that location are the same as for any location with the same 'y'.

Comment: Oh so at each point in a cross section same electric field? Is it something like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Linear_Polarization_Linearly_Polarized_Light_plane_wave.svg/450px-Linear_Polarization_Linearly_Polarized_Light_plane_wave.svg.png

Comment: @newage2000, yes, like that.

Answer (score 2):

The picture represents an EM wave traversing in y direction. Those arrows represent vectors of **E** and **H** components of the wave, which are perpendicular to each other. In fact, those vectors represent the time varying amplitude of the z-component of the **E** wave and the x-component of the **H** wave at different points along y. Keep in mind that, EM waves may also have **E** and **H** components in all 3 axes. This figure simply represents magnitude and directions of these vectors. So the point 'X' you marked is not actually a spatial dimension point, but just a point on this vector space. It can be a part of some other EM wave with higher amplitude.